# linq to sql left outer join not giving expected results

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have been trying to get the below SQL query to give me same result while using in Linq but i am not getting desired result. I know there are some other posts regarding left outer join in linq but they don't give me expected result so i thought to put query itself. Kindly provide me with linq query for below SQL query.

```
Select vbk.*, 
       adm.admFullName 
from   Voucherbooks vbk
       left outer join adminlogins adm 
           on vbk.vbkauthid = adm.admid
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var results = Voucherbooks
    .GroupJoin
    (
        adminlogins,
        x=>x.vbkauthid,
        x=>x.admid
        (vbk,adm)=>new
        {
            vbk,
            admFullName = adm.FirstOrDefault() == null 
                ? String.Empty 
                : adm.FirstOrDefault().admFullName
        }
    )
```